# SSH to Raspberry Pi Headless on New Networks

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, ssh

So im 3 days in to working on the rPi. My current issue is trying to `ssh` in to my Pi on new networks. I have successfully connected to my Pi via ssh on networks that I have manually logged in to (using raspbian os UI).

### what I've tried:

Modifying where the `wpa_supplicant.conf` is read from in `etc/network/interfaces` to read from `/boot`

adding an `ssh` file in the `boot` partition of the sd card.

I can `ping` the router and get all of the connected `ip` address and can see that it is connecting to the network; showing me that, my modification to the path of where remembered networks is working. However, I am getting a `connection refused` and a `connection timed out` error when trying to ssh in now.

Any leads in the right direction are greatly appriciated.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

First make sure the Raspberry got its IP address (i.e. is successfully connected with the network) and you can ping it at all. SSH should work then, unless a firewall is blocking its port (22) or connections between hosts are disabled (i.e. host isolation - common on wireless networks).
I assume you've got a Raspberry on a wired network, because wireless won't go online on unknown networks.

The easier way:

Use a program called Adafruit Pi Finder ( https://learn.adafruit.com/the-adafruit-raspberry-pi-finder/overview )

The harder way:

If a Unix/Linux computer is available, try:

```
ip addr
```

Find your IP address and determine the subnet address. Most typically the 192.168.x.y is used for local area networks, and unless it's very specific, the 255.255.255.0 or /24 (24 bits out of 32 bits which form the full IPv4 address) subnet mask is used. It means that the last number (y) determines the individual host, and the preceding numbers (192.168.x) determine the subnet.

Now you need to scan the network with nmap (if it's not installed, get it with your package manager):

```
nmap -sP 192.168.x.0/24
```

If you do it as an administrator, i.e.

```
sudo nmap -sP 192.168.x.0/24
```

you'll probably see the MAC addresses and manufacturers of the devices connected to the network. The Raspberry will probably be there.

Answer (score 0):

Ive had issues doing the same when the pi is connected to a new network via WiFi. I'm not a network expert, but because of the many variables that change from one network to another I think connecting via WiFi on all of them will be a challenge. However, via ethernet, can you not just give it a unique static ip that can accessed? I even use the DHCP server on my computer when connected via ethernet and can always ssh in.